# PostgreSQL, need to update some tables from CSV file

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a DB with discount card records, i need to copy the info from main DB to other with the same struckture. Need to update the fields name, phone etc from the main DB. The info i need is in three tables: 1.pers_cards (the card numbers). 2.pers_clients (the name, phone, etc). 3 pers_accounts (the table combine two previous table by fields client_id and account_id)
I wrote script to get the info i need:

```
Copy (SELECT pers_cards.card_num, pers_clients.name, pers_clients.address, 
             pers_clients.phone, pers_clients.mobilephone, pers_clients.email, 
             pers_clients.birthday,pers_clients.gender_male
      FROM   pers_cards,pers_accounts,pers_clients 
      WHERE (
          pers_accounts.client_id = pers_clients.client_id 
          and 
          pers_cards.acc_id = pers_accounts.acc_id 
      ))
To 'f:/test.csv' With CSV;
```

Now i need to update the other BD using this file, update fields with personal info (pers_clients.name, pers_clients.phone etc) depending of its card number.
trouble is the fields client_id and account_id has different values in different tables.

```
CREATE TABLE cards_temp
(card_num varchar, name varchar, address varchar, 
phone varchar, mobilephone varchar, email varchar, birthday date, gender_male bool);

COPY cards_temp FROM 'f:/test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;

UPDATE cards cards
SET name = cards_temp.name
FROM cards_temp
WHERE cards_temp.card_num = cards.card_num;
```

How to update my main table:

```
UPDATE pers_clients 
SET name = cards_temp.name
FROM cards_temp
WHERE cards_temp.card_num = (SELECT pers_cards.card_num
FROM pers_cards,pers_accounts,pers_clients 
WHERE (
pers_accounts.client_id = pers_clients.client_id and pers_cards.acc_id = pers_accounts.acc_id ));
```

Comment: ... and this is tagged `mysql` why?

Comment: scripting language is the same, isnt it ?

Comment: Er, no. They share a common subset, SQL, but the command languages are far from the same. If they were, there'd be no point having `postgresql` and `mysql` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can JOIN your TEMP table and using fields from it update your main one

```
UPDATE pers_clients AS clients
SET name = tmp_cards.name, 
    address = tmp_cards.address, 
    phone = tmp_cards.phone,
    mobilephone = tmp_cards.mobilephone,
    email = tmp_cards.email,
    birthday = tmp_cards.birthday,
    gender_male = tmp_cards.gender_male
FROM pers_accounts AS accounts, pers_cards AS cards, cards_temp AS tmp_cards
WHERE accounts.client_id = clients.client_id
AND accounts.acc_id = cards.acc_id 
AND cards.card_num = tmp_cards.card_num
```

Comment: U r my saver, works perfectly, thats what i was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to:

- create an `UNLOGGED` table with the structure of the CSV data
- `COPY` the data to the new unlogged table
- Use a series of SQL `UPDATE ... FROM` statements to update each target table using a join against the unlogged table full of temporary data
- Drop the unlogged table